# Will AWS Autoscaling group with MixedInstancesPolicy launch On-Demand instance if no spot instances available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using AutoscalingGroup with mixed policy, where OnDemandBaseCapacity and OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity are 0, so it won't launch any On-Demand instance but always try to request and launch spot instance when needed.
My Cloudformation Spec for autoscaling group:

```
  AutoScalingGroupForApiServers:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref VpcSubnetsForApiLoadBalancer
      MinSize: !Ref ASGMinSizeForApiServers
      MaxSize: !Ref ASGMaxSizeForApiServers
      HealthCheckType: !Ref HealthCheckTypeForApiServers
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: !FindInMap [ Constants, '-', AutoScalingGroupDefaultHealthCheckGracePeriod ]
      MixedInstancesPolicy:
        InstancesDistribution:
          OnDemandBaseCapacity: 0
          OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity: 0
          SpotAllocationStrategy: lowest-price
          SpotInstancePools: 2
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateSpecification:
            LaunchTemplateId: !Ref AutoScalingLaunchTemplateForApiServers
            Version: !GetAtt AutoScalingLaunchTemplateForApiServers.LatestVersionNumber
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - !Ref ElasticLoadBalancerForApiServers
```

I have two questions:
1) If one spot instance terminates and there's no another spot instance available, will it launch On-Demand instance and then scale down it to 0?
2) Upon receiving 2-minute termination notice will it automatically throw out instance from referenced load balancers/target groups or do I have manually handle it with CloudWatch/SNS/Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

`1) If one spot instance terminates and there's no another spot instance available, will it launch On-Demand instance and then scale down it to 0?`
it will try to maintain the OnDemand:Spot ratio which you would have mentioned in config. for example if you have set 30% OnDemand and 70% Spot. then it will keep the autoscaling group instances as 30% OnDemand and 70% Spot. if Spot instances are not available then it wont launch OnDemand instances to compensate it.
`2) Upon receiving 2-minute termination notice will it automatically throw out instance from referenced load balancers/target groups or do I have manually handle it with CloudWatch/SNS/Lambda?`
if you have linked AutoScaling group with Targetgroup, then it will automatically removes the Terminated or unavailable instances from the TargetGroups.